# git log displays nothing for all projects

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, git-log

I have been using git for many years. But suddenly, `git log` command started displaying nothing. When I type `git log` command, it simply ends and displays nothing.

The command `git rev-list --all --pretty` does return all the commits along with other informations.

```
commit b89bbaafc0854b57230d5e5018dd72d48106eb03
Merge: 96758ec 60c87e1
Author: Ali Ayub Khan <akhan.bscs15seecs@seecs.edu.pk>
Date:   Sat May 19 14:05:01 2018 +0500

Merge pull request #33 from hkedia321/master

fix #32 - update readme and ping heroku to prevent from sleeping
```

So, the "git log" command started displaying nothing. I uninstalled git and reinstalled also, but it still doesn't work. This is same for all the projects (new and old both). I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.Can someone please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I only now found the moved-to-chat discussion.)

I suggested using `git --no-pager log`, which worked.  I then asked what `git var GIT_PAGER` produced, and what program that redirected to; the answers were:

```
$ git var GIT_PAGER
pager
$ which pager
/home/hkedia321/anaconda3/bin/pager
```

Others had asked about the exit status, which was 141: this indicates a SIGPIPE on Linux.

So, what this means is that the program living in this location—`/home/hkedia321/anaconda3/bin/pager`—is somehow faulty.  Instead of showing output one page at a time, it simply exits without showing anything, or dies of a SIGPIPE signal.  I'll note here that `pager` on my own Ubuntu 16.04 system is `/usr/bin/pager`, which is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/pager`, which is itself a symlink to `/bin/less`.

(My own `git var GIT_PAGER` produces `less` so that I go through `/bin/less` much more directly.)

Your two options are therefore:

- fix this `pager` program so that it works, or
- avoid this particular `pager` program.

The latter is easy enough if you prefer `less` as your pager since you can simply run:

```
git config --global core.pager less
```

(which is specific to Git only), or export the setting:

```
PAGER=less
```

in your environment, which is what I do on Linux systems, using this code fragment in my `.profile` file:

```
# bash and sh use "type" a bit differently, but both will
# exit 0 if the command exists (or is an alias).
command_exists() {
        type "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# if less exists, use it as pager; if lesspipe exists, set its env too
command_exists less && {
        export PAGER=less
        export LESS=FRX
        command_exists lesspipe && eval $(lesspipe)
}
```

(this is specific to Unix-like systems using sh or bash, although it attempts to be self-tuning).